# Multi Store with Subdomains

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, shopify, velo, online-store

I want to create multiple online shops for selling merchandise products for companies. The products are basically identical but should be personalized in dependence of the company I am building the shop for. Because I do not want to build a new shop every time a new company joins the program I am looking for something like that:

**[www.myshop.com](http://www.myshop.com)** : One shop with the underlying product database and checkout system - not showing any products, just as a parent structure

**[www.company1.myshop.com](http://www.company1.myshop.com)** : A slightly personalized shop where only a selection of the product catalogue is available

**[www.company2.myshop.com](http://www.company2.myshop.com)** : A slightly personalized shop where a different selection of the product catalogue is available

Do you get it?

Does anybody know a tool for that?

Thanks in advance!

I already looked into WooCommerce, Shopify and even WiX. As far as I understood what I am looking for is not supported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your example is based off of subdomains, you can choose to assign a Shopify store to each subdomain. Each store feeds from your inventory and accounting, giving your customers the illusion of a custom experience. Or you can just simplify your life, have one store, and assign your customers to view collections specific to them. That is the smart move. You may not like that, but it would work a peach for you. You just tag customers to see their specific collections, of products specific to those collections. Simple.

I can also think of a dozen other ways to pull this off with Shopify, but that is me, not you. For an opinion question like this, SO is not the right place to ask these kinds of questions, but I answered anyway. Your mileage may vary of course.